# save an image with two UIImageView which has two images - ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

In my application I have two `UIImageViews` which is overlayed one over the other. i.e ) `UIImageView-2` is placed on `UIImageView-1`. The image in `UIImageView-2` is transparent, so now I have image over another image. Now I need to save these two as a single image. Is it possible in ios? Please advice..

**The sample view is as below:** The red mark is an image in a view over tennis ball image view.

[image]

Comment: Here is the answer which you looking for this exactly slimier to your need. visit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453913/how-can-i-add-two-uiimageview-and-save-it-to-iphone-photo-gallery-in-iphone-appl

Answer (score 4):

Hope following method will help you.

```
-(CGImageRef )mergedImageFromImageOne:(UIImage *)imageOne andImageTwo:(UIImage *)imageTwo
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    CGSize imageSize = imageOne.size;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sizeVideo);

    [imageOne drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,imageSize.width,imageSize.height)];

    [imageTwo drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,imageSize.width,imageSize.height) alpha:1];

    CGImageRef imageRefNew =  CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext().CGImage, CGRectMake(0,0,imageOne.width,imageOne.height));

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [pool release];

    return imageRefNew;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've taken one **Logo Image** which is set on main image as application ref.

So you can refer this, try with your images.

**set width(w) & height(h) as per your image.**

Try this ::

```
UIImage *img_Logo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Img_Logo.png"];

CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(w, h);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);

// Use existing opacity as is
[main_image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

// Apply supplied opacity
[img_Logo drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.8];

main_image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

imgView.image = main_image;
```

Hope, this'll help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Why you are not taking screenshot for only that portion??**